# Someone answered a duplicate question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, exact-duplicates, closed-questions

I was surprised when I saw a question rise to the top of Mi Yodeya's stack, that said "answered," while the question title said duplicate.

Is this a bug?

[image: Screenshot showing "Marked as duplicate ... 5 mins ago" and "answered 27 secs ago"]

Here's a [link to the question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/51374/5323); here's a [link to the answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/51379/5323).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91928/162102) after a question is put on hold during which an answer *that was started before the question was put on hold* can still be submitted.  The rather-old MSE post I linked to says this grace period is around 4 hours, but my own observation has been that it's somewhere around 30-60 minutes nowadays.

Also, apparently the mobile client (I don't know if that's mobile web, apps, or both) doesn't notice that the question was closed while you were answering, so that will always go through.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed/91928?noredirect=1#comment807401_91928 *et seqq.*